# user instance with id 1L does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, postgis, geodjango

In Django Project I am using two databases, first is MySQL second is PostgreSQL, in PostgreSQL I have only geometric values but I need users too, so In models I have:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class geo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    location = models.PointField()
```

Everything is working fine but when I try to save, user field shows an error **user instance with id 1L does not exist** So what could be the answer? Is problem coming from the router.py file?

Comment: It clearly means the model is expecting a class instance, and you are sending it the object id.

Comment: Are you trying to have relationship across 2 different databases? That is not possible. However, a crud way is to store user id as string/int instead of foriegnkey.

Comment: Foreign key should always be a reference of primary key, their should not be a default value. Just try to remove it and whenever you want to create or update in the geo model just provide the primary key objects instead of direct value of user.

Comment: still not working

Comment: @huseyinozanhonamlioglu You said **everything is works fine but when I try to save** where are you trying to save it??  Show the code of that view/function.

Comment: Bro problem comes from inside database, models are working good, it creates table aut_user inside mysql and postgresql both, but when I create user it only affects aut_user table inside mysql, so postgresql's auth_user is still empty, now I am trying to create router for django.contrib.auth app, Do you have any idea for this

Comment: @huseyinozanhonamlioglu That's what I am asking you, Where is the code to create any user or any geo model?? Show us the code, then only I can help you.

Comment: Create geo model is that i showed below and create user model is the django.contrib.auth man

Comment: @huseyinozanhonamlioglu Updated my answer. Please check. use this code for geo model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133800/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-huseyin-ozan-honamlioglu).

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from this line :

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
```

Here you are defining **default=1** so when you are not assigning any user instance to **user** field of **geo** model, default then user field is taking integer default value, but it is expecting a user instance.

There are two solutions :

1. At the time of creation of new instance/record of **geo** model, add a user instance to it.

**Or**

2. Use **blank=True, null=True** in your **geo** model,like this:

   ```
   class geo(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
       location = models.PointField()
   ```

I would personally recommend the second method. Thanks.